# Refering two columns with data from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with my SQL homework. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 17. In my table, I have a column for CustomerID1 and CustomerID2. I want to connect the id with another table called Customer and it has the Id as primary key and fullname. The output that I want is Customer1Name and Customer2Name. How do I connect two tables?

```
select c.FullName from Sales s, Customer c where s.CustomerID1 = c.Id

select c.FullName from Sales s, Customer c where s.CustomerID2 = c.Id
```

This is what i am trying to do but i wanted it to be in one sentence if it is possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why does your table have two CustomerID columns?

Comment: Ohh never heard of JOIN before. I will look into it, thanks mate!

Comment: It's sort of like referred by. Like who introduced the buyer to the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select c1.FullName as Customer1Name, c2.FullName as Customer2Name
from Sales s
left join Customer c1 
on s.CustomerID1 = c1.Id 
left join Customer c2 
on s.CustomerID2 = c2.Id
```